# I'd like to understand Java's SecureRandom object

Tags: java, random, cryptography

While doing a beginner's crypto course I'm trying to get to grips with Java's SecureRandom object. What I think I understand is that:

a) No matter how long a sequence of random numbers you know, there is no way of predicting the next random number in the sequence.

b) No matter how long a sequence of random numbers you know, there is no way of knowing which seed was used to start them off, other than brute force guesswork.

c) You can request secure random numbers of various sizes.

d) You can seed a newly-created SRNG with various different-sized values. Every newly-created SRNG you create and seed with the same value will produce the same sequence of random numbers.

I should add that I'm assuming that this code is used on Windows:

```
Random sr = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG", "SUN");
```

Is my basic understanding correct? Thanks in advance.

I have some further questions for anyone who's reasonably expert in crypto. They relate to seeding a SRNG as opposed to letting it seed itself on first use.

e) What difference, if any, does it make to the random numbers generated, if you seed a SRNG with a long integer as opposed to an array of 8 bytes?

f) If I seed a SRNG with, say, 256 bytes is there any other seed that can produce the same sequence of random numbers?

g) Is there some kind of optimum seed size? It seems to me that this might be a meaningless question.

h) If I encrypt a plaintext by seeding a SRNG with, say, 256 bytes then getting it to generate random bytes to XOR with the bytes in the plaintext, how easy would it be for an eavesdropper to decrypt the resulting ciphertext? How long might it take? Am I right in thinking that the eavesdropper would have to know, guess, or calculate the 256-byte seed?

I've looked at previous questions about SecureRandom and none seem to answer my particular concerns.
If any of these questions seem overly stupid, I'd like to reiterate that I'm very much a beginner in studying this field. I'd be very grateful for any input as I want to understand how Java SecureRandom objects might be used in cryptography.

Comment: That's a lot of questions for one question.  I think your understanding is largely correct, though.

Comment: Sorry about the number of questions. It's my first post here.

Comment: These are good questions, but answering each one deserve a couple of paragraphs. I would recommend posting them separately. BTW, please clarify if you want an answer specific to the SHA1PRNG algorithm, or more broad about Pseudo-RNG.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, in order:

a) correct

b) correct

c) correct, you can even request a number in a range [0, n) using `nextInt(n)`

d) as good as correct: the implementation of SHA1PRNG is not publicly defined by any algorithm and there are indications that the implementation *has* changed in time, so this is only true for the Sun provider, and then only for a specific runtime configuration

e) as the API clearly indicates that all the bytes within the long are used ("using the eight bytes contained in the given long seed") there should not be any difference regarding the amount of entropy added to the state

Note that a quick check shows that `setSeed(long)` behaves entirely different from `setSeed(byte[])` with the main difference that the seed of the `long` value is always mixed in with randomness retrieved from the system, even if it is the first call after the `SecureRandom` instance is constructed.

f) yes - an infinite number of seeds generate the same stream; since a hash function is used, it will be impossible to find one though

g) if you mix in additional entropy, then the more entropy the better, but there is no minimum; if you use it as the only seed then you should not start off with less than 20 bytes of seed, that is: if you want to keep the seed to the same security constraints as the inner state of the PRNG

And I would add that if you use less than 64 bytes of entropy you are in the danger zone for sure. Note that 1 bit of entropy does not always mean 1 bit in a byte. A byte array of size 8 may have 64 bits of entropy *or less*.

h) that's basically a hash based stream cipher; it's secure, so an attacker has little to no chance (*given you don't reuse the seed*) but it is a horribly unreliable (see answer d) and slow stream cipher, so please never ever do this - use a `Cipher` with  `"AES/CTR/NoPadding"` or `"AES/GCM/NoPadding"` instead

Comment: Great! That addresses every single point where I've lacked full comprehension, and then some. And also pointed me towards some more research topics. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 2):

d)  This is true for a PRNG.  It is not always true for a CSRNG.  Read the Javadoc for `SecureRandom.setSeed()`: "The given seed supplements, rather than replaces, the existing seed. Thus, repeated calls are guaranteed never to reduce randomness."

Any reasonable CSRNG will have "invisible" sources of entropy that you cannot explicitly control, often various internal parameters taken from the Operating System level.  Hence there is more seeding than any number you explicitly pass to the RNG.

Comment: Thanks. I'd read this in the Javadoc but ran a series of successive calls to seed a new SecureRandom then ask it for a succession of long values. It came out with the same numbers every time. I don't remember how many times I repeated the test but if it's going to vary even once then such a seed can't be used to both encrypt and decrypt to the same message every time.

Comment: If you are encrypting and decrypting, then you need a [Stream Cipher](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_cipher), like RC4 or one of the [eSTREAM](http://www.ecrypt.eu.org/stream/) ciphers.  A stream cypher is fundamentally a PRNG where the output is entirely dependent on the seed/key.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm not encrypting or decrypting. I'm studying. And trying to find out the weaknesses of using a seeded Java SecureRandom object.

Answer (score 1):

e) I don't think that it makes a difference.  Assuming that the long and the 8-byte array contain the same data.

f) In principle, yes. If your seed is larger than the internal state of the RNG, then there may exist some other seed that will result in the same internal state.  If the seed is smaller than the state, then there shouldn't be.  I don't know what SecureRandom's internal state looks like.

g) It's not the size of the seed that matters; it's the amount of entropy in it.  You need there to be at least as much entropy in your seed as the security you expect out of the RNG; I'm not quite sure what best practices are here.

h) I'm not sure how easy it would be to break the RNG-based stream cipher that you propose.  But I would recommend against using it in practice, because it's not a standard cryptographic construction that has been reviewed by experts and has reasonable security proofs.  Remember the Rules of Crypto:

1. Never design your own crypto.
2. Never implement your own crypto.
3. Anyone can design crypto that they can't break themselves.

Comment: Thanks. I'm just trying to understand. And wondering just how weak it would be using a SRNG seeded with any particular value I chose, as opposed to, say /dev/urandom or the equivalent.

Comment: Given that humans aren't very good at generating random numbers, I'd strongly advise against making up your own seeds.  Also, if you use a hard-coded seed, the random stream will be the same every time.

Comment: Yes, I realise this, thanks. I'm not trying to encrypt anything, I'm just trying to understand why this kind of crypto is weak, and how long it would take to break it.